# Eager Loading, Model methods, fields_for, each and N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a reasonably complex application (over 30 tables) that has some persistent N+1 issues, and I'm presuming it is because I am not doing something 'The Rails Way™'

I'm going to give and example of one of the more complicated ones.  This one includes four tables: `clins, positions_tasks, tasks` and `labor_hours`.

`positions_tasks` is a three-way many-to-many join between `clins, positions`(which isn't needed for this example), and `tasks`, and it `has_many :labor_hours`.  The labor_hours table has an integer field for each month of a year and some other data. A method, `total_hours`, sums all of the months into a total hours for the year.  In the clin view, it displays the clin information and a table of all associated tasks [with other related data], and sums the hours for each of the tasks, which `has_many :labor_hours, :through => :positions_tasks`.  I eager load all of the relevant tables, including labor_hours, and all of the N+1 problems went away except for labor_hours.

Code snippets follow.

The clins_controller's eager load:

```
@clin = Clin.includes(:proposal).includes(:positions_tasks).includes(:tasks).includes(:labor_hours).includes(:wbss).find(params[:id])`
```

Displaying the table rows inside clins/_form.html.erb:

```
    <tbody>
        <% @clin.tasks.distinct.each do |t| %>
          <%= f.fields_for :task, t do |builder| %>
            <%= render "tasks/task_row", f: builder %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

The _task_row partial:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= f.object.wbs_line_item.wbs.wbs_title %></td>
    <td><%= f.object.wbs_line_item.wbs_line_item %></td>
    <td><%= f.object.description %></td>
    <td><%= f.object.labor_hours.distinct.each.sum(&:total_hours) %>
    <td><div id="jump">
      <%= link_to "Edit", {:controller => :tasks, :action => :edit, :id => f.object.id } %>
    </div></td>
</tr>
```

The clin model:

```
class Clin < ActiveRecord::Base
  nilify_blanks

  belongs_to :proposal

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Clin"
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Clin"

  has_many :positions_tasks
  has_many :labor_hours, :through => :positions_tasks
  has_many :tasks, :through => :positions_tasks
  has_many :wbs_line_items, :through => :tasks
  has_many :wbss, :through => :wbs_line_items
  has_many :pws_line_items, :through => :wbs_line_items
  has_many :pwss, :through => :wbss
end
```

Labor hours model:

```
class LaborHours < ActiveRecord::Base
  nilify_blanks

  belongs_to :positions_task
  belongs_to :year

  has_one :proposal, :through => :positions_task
  has_many :valid_years, :through => :proposal, :source => :years

  def total_hours
    m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5 + m6 + m7 + m8 + m9 + m10 + m11 + m12
  end
end
```

The positionsTask model:

```
class PositionsTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  nilify_blanks

  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :position
  belongs_to :clin

  has_many :labor_hours

  has_one :company, :through => :position
  has_one :proposal, :through => :clin
  has_one :wbs_line_item, :through => :task
  delegate :wbs, :to => :wbs_line_item

  delegate :pws_line_items, :to => :wbs_line_item
  delegate :pwss, :to => :wbs_line_item

  validates_presence_of :task
  validates_presence_of :position
  validates_presence_of :clin

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :labor_hours, allow_destroy: true
end
```

The Task model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  nilify_blanks

  belongs_to :wbs_line_item
  belongs_to :task_category

  has_many :positions_tasks

  has_many :labor_hours, :through => :positions_tasks
  has_many :positions, :through => :positions_tasks
  has_many :clins, :through => :positions_tasks
  has_many :proposals, :through => :positions_tasks

  delegate :wbs, :to => :wbs_line_item
  delegate :pws_line_items, :to => :wbs_line_item
  delegate :pwss, :to => :wbs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions_tasks, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :labor_hours, allow_destroy: true

  validates_associated :positions_tasks

end
```

The GET and SQL loads:

```
Started GET "/clins/11/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-20 17:48:49 -0400
Processing by ClinsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11"}
  Clin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "clins".* FROM "clins" WHERE "clins"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
  Proposal Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "proposals".* FROM "proposals" WHERE "proposals"."id" IN (1)
  PositionsTask Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "positions_tasks".* FROM "positions_tasks" WHERE "positions_tasks"."clin_id" IN (11)
  Task Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 23, 24)
  LaborHours Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" WHERE "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 35, 36, 37)
  WbsLineItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "wbs_line_items".* FROM "wbs_line_items" WHERE "wbs_line_items"."id" IN (310, 312, 314, 316, 317, 318, 319, 413, 320, 321, 322, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 330, 333, 334)
  Wbs Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "wbss".* FROM "wbss" WHERE "wbss"."id" IN (1)
  Clin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "clins".* FROM "clins"
  Rendered tasks/_task_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (2.6ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 2]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.7ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 3]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.4ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 5]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.3ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 6]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.4ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 7]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.5ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 8]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.3ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 9]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.3ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 10]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.9ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 11]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.5ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 12]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (2.2ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 14]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (2.6ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 15]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (2.2ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 16]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.5ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 17]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.9ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 18]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.6ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 20]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.9ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 23]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.6ms)
  LaborHours Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "labor_hours".* FROM "labor_hours" INNER JOIN "positions_tasks" ON "labor_hours"."positions_task_id" = "positions_tasks"."id" WHERE "positions_tasks"."task_id" = $1  [["task_id", 24]]
  Rendered tasks/_task_row.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered clins/_form.html.erb (47.6ms)
  Rendered clins/_errors.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered clins/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (48.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (60.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidenav.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 140ms (Views: 106.4ms | ActiveRecord: 8.8ms)
```

I think that what is happening is that the eager loading is getting lost in the `distinct.each` and `fields_for` in _form.html.erb because it is passing the task objects instead of the clin object, and/or that the call to total_hours is causing a load for each object it is called on, but I'm not sure how to determine which it is, nor how to resolve them.

How do I provide the summed `task.labor_hours.total_hours` for each task in the table without the N+1 loading of the labor_hours?

Comment: Protip (that doesn't help solve your problem at all): You can pass more than one argument to `includes`: `Clin.includes(:proposal, :positions_tasks, :tasks, :labor_hours, :wbss).find(params[:id])`

Comment: I will use that convention from now on. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I've a theory. You have this (I've removed the `includes` calls that don't concern us just now:

```
@clin = Clin.includes(:tasks).includes(:labor_hours).find(params[:id])
```

What you're doing here is eager-loading the Tasks associated with each Clin and the LaborHours associated with each Clin—so far, so good, but in your view you're doing this (more or less):

```
@clin.tasks.distinct.each do |task|
  # inside the partial...
  task.labor_hours...
end
```

Here you're not accessing the LaborHours associated each Clin—which is what you eager-loaded—you're accessing the LaborHours associated with each Task associated with each Clin. To access the LaborHours associated with each Clin, you'd have to do this:

```
@clin.labor_hours.each do |labor_hour|
  # ...
end
```

But since you are rendering the Tasks (and not just the LaborHours), I don't think that's what you want. Instead, you need to tell Rails that you want to eager-load the second-order association—i.e. LaborHours associated with the *Tasks*, not the LaborHours associated with the Clins—by passing a hash to `includes`:

```
@clin = Clin.includes(:tasks => :labor_hours).find(params[:id])
```

P.S. There's some additional improvement you could make—for example, it looks like you're not actually using any of the attributes from LaborHours, you're actually just using the sum of the `total_hours` column. But calculating the sum in Ruby is a waste when you can just let the database do it. However, that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: You rock. I updated the controller to: `@clin = Clin.includes(:proposal, :positions_tasks, :wbss).includes(:tasks => :labor_hours).find(params[:id])` and the N+1 is resolved.

Comment: Great! You can also do `Clin.includes(:proposal, :positions_tasks, :wbss, :tasks => :labor_hours).find(params[:id])`

Comment: I tried `Clin.includes(:proposal, :positions_tasks, :tasks => :labor_hours, :wbss).find(params[:id])` and NetBeans didn't like it, so I did the other, but it is fine with it at the end, as you typed it. On the side note, what do I have to put in a model/migration to get the database to do the addition for me?